# Can the web host disable meta tag redirection

Tags: redirect, meta-tags

I want to have a page redirect to another. Here is the situation:

- I don't have access to the server config, and can't use any server redirection (don't know if that's the term)
- Only ASP is installed
- The index file MUST be main.html (changing it to main.asp results in what seems to be an infinite refresh loop)

I'd like to stay away from JavaScript redirects, so ideally I'd use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0";url="site_url">`. But this results in, again, an infinite refresh loop.

I'm wondering if I am making a mistake, or if the host has disabled this type of redirection.

Bonus: If meta and server redirection are not options, is there anything left besides JavaScript redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should have written this way :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=site_url">
```

Comment: site_url must be inside content.

Comment: Silly mistake. Surely one of my finer moments :)